# How to train imbalanced data with Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to experiment on ISIC 2019 data as a newbie. Firstly, I downloaded the training data and divided the data into 3 parts as train, test, and validation data, and every dataset folder contains 2 subfolders which are benign and malignant. In short, I just moved all the categories into benign folders except the melenoma category and melanoma images are inside malignant folders. After the division, I get imbalanced data. In the training dataset for benign data, I get 16596 images and for malignant data, I get 3629 images. I tried to train my data and I couldn't get a good result for malignant and my precision value was about 0.18 for malignant. I used ResNet50 to train my model and I would like to ask how can I train my model without data augmentation and oversampling? I am also trying decayed learning metrics at the moment and it seems it won't give a good result too.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalMaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_examples = 20225
test_examples = 2551
validation_examples = 2555
img_height = img_width = 224
channel = 3
batch_size = 32

base_model = ResNet50(weights = 'imagenet' , include_top = False, input_shape = (img_height, img_width, channel))
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(
    inputs = base_model.input,
    outputs = x)
model.summary()

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range = 20,
    width_shift_range=0.10,
    height_shift_range=0.10,
    zoom_range = 0.10,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    preprocessing_function = preprocess_input,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function = preprocess_input,
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function = preprocess_input,
)

train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "dataset/train/",
    target_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    color_mode = "rgb",
    class_mode = "binary",
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 123,
)

validation_gen = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "dataset/validation/",
    target_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    color_mode = "rgb",
    class_mode = "binary",
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 123,
)

test_gen = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "dataset/test/",
    target_size =(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    color_mode = "rgb",
    class_mode = "binary",
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 123,
)

METRICS = [
    keras.metrics.Precision(name = "precision"),
    keras.metrics.Recall(name = "recall"),
    keras.metrics.AUC(name = "auc"),
]

model.compile(
    optimizer = Adam(lr = 3e-4),
    loss = [keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits = False)],
    metrics = METRICS,
)

history = model.fit(train_gen,
                    epochs=50,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=validation_gen,
                    callbacks=[keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("isic_binary_model")],
                )
```

Comment: why are you trying to train without data-augmentation and oversampling?

Comment: I was wondering if there was another method besides those because with oversampling you would need more time to train your model.

Comment: You can use `class_wight` in Keras. You can give more weightage to the class having fewer data and less to the one having more of it. Read more about it's implementation [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras)

Comment: I tried ```class_weights``` before I got a low precision on my malignant data. Maybe I didn't train my data enough. How many epochs should I train my model for this data?

Comment: You aren't freezing the classification part( base-model ) of your model. Generally, the procedure is we freeze the whole base model and just train the last layer ( Dense ) with a higher learning rate( 1e-2 ) and then unfreeze some last convolutional layers or whole of the base model and then train the whole model( not just the base model ) with a lower learning rate( 1e-4 or so ). No of epochs vary from data to data. Try to start off with 20 epochs and then see the results through Epoch-Accuracy and Epoch-Loss plot and then increase the no of epochs gradually.

Comment: I never used freezing it is a new concept for me. What would change only training the last layer? Can you give me an example, please? How can I implement this in my model?

Comment: The feature extraction part( base-model ) is already extracting features from the training data. We are just replacing the last softmax layer as per our need( our no of classes can be different from that of the base - model ). Then we train the last layer so that it gets accustomed to the input it receives from the convolutional base( base-model ). If we have a bit more data, we can then fine-tune the whole network or just unfreeze the last layers of the base-model to customize itself 'specifically' to our training data.

Comment: @Sarunam In my 3rd comment( You aren't freezing the.... ) I have inadvertently referred to base-model as classification part in the first line. This is wrong. The classification part is generally the FC Layers and convolutional layers constitute the 'Feature Extraction' layer or 'Convolutional-Part' of the model.